# How to call secure web service in Adobe Experience Manager using certificate?

Tags: rest, security, ssl, certificate, aem

using Adobe AEM as cloud service , i need to call third party services and authenticate with certificate  (pfx file)

ssl handshake failed exception

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract pfx information
2. Create system user.
3. Map the system user.
4. Add the certificate to this user.
5. Create Servlet that will run under that user

[here is my post (i answered myself](https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/call-third-part-y-rest-service-from-aem-as-cloud-using/m-p/576461/highlight/true#M144133)

Answer (score 0):

To make secure third-party HTTP calls from AEM as a Cloud using certificates, you need to perform several steps including creating a service user, storing certificates in keystores, and setting up secure HTTP calls.

**1. Create a Service User in AEM as a Cloud**

The first step is to create a service user which acts as a bridge between AEM and the third-party API. Create a file with the name `org.apache.sling.jcr.repoinit.RepositoryInitializer~[generic-name].cfg.json` in the directory `../ui.config/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/[your-project-name]/osgiconfig/config`.

Inside this file, include the following configuration:

```
{
"scripts": [
    "create path (sling:OrderedFolder) /content/dam/[folder-name]",
    "create path (nt:unstructured) /content/dam/[folder-name]/jcr:content",
    "set properties on /content/dam/[folder-name]/jcr:content\n  set cq:conf{String} to /conf/[folder-name]\n  set jcr:title{String} to \"[folder-name]\"\nend",
    "create service user [your-service-user-name]\n set ACL for [your-service-user-name]\n allow jcr:read on /content \nend"
]}
```

**3. Store Certificates in Keystores**

The next step is to store the necessary certificates in keystores. Use the command `keytool -v -list -keystore certificatename.pfx` to list the aliases in a PFX keystore. Here is a complete guide on [uploading the PFX file](https://developer.adobe.com/events/docs/guides/using/aem/deprecated/aem_keystore_setup_6.4/).

**4. Create a Class to Get the Keystore**

You need to create a class in Java to get the keystore. Here's a sample code for the same:

```
public class PrivateKeyCertificate {

@Reference
private KeyStoreService keyStoreService;

public KeyStore getKeyStore(ResourceResolver resourceResolver) throws SlingIOException, SecurityException, KeyStoreNotInitialisedException, LoginException, org.apache.sling.api.resource.LoginException, IOException {
    KeyStore keyStore = keyStoreService.getKeyStore(null, "[service-user-name]");
    return keyStore;
}
```

**With the extracted alias and password, use the following code snippet to generate the SSL socket factory:**

```
public static SSLSocketFactory setKeyStoreSSLFactories(KeyStore keyStore, String keystoreType, char[] keyStorePassword) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

    KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

    keyFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword);

    KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

    sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, null);
    SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);

    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
```

**5. Apply Secure HTTP Calls**

Finally, you can apply secure HTTP calls in AEM as a Cloud. Here is a sample servlet which uses the keystore to make a secure HTTP call:

```
public class YourServlet {

@Inject
PrivateKeyCertificate privateKeyCertificate;

protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        ResourceResolver resourceResolver = request.getResourceResolver();
        KeyStore keyStore = privateKeyCertificate.getKeyStore(resourceResolver);
        char[] keyStorePassword = "your_keystore_password".toCharArray(); // Replace with your keystore password
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLFactoryUtil.setKeyStoreSSLFactories(keyStore, "JKS", keyStorePassword);
        
        // URL of the target resource
        URL targetUrl = new URL("https://www.example.com");
        
        // Open HTTPS connection
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) targetUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
        
        try (InputStream is = connection.getInputStream()) {
            // Process the input stream
        }
        
        // Rest of your servlet code...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

Remember to replace `[your-project-name]`, `[your-service-user-name]`, `your_keystore_password`, and the target URL as per your specific requirements.

By following these steps, you can successfully make secure third-party HTTP calls from AEM as a Cloud using certificates.